# Oracle PL/SQL Use Merge command on data from XML Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a PL/SQL procedure that currently gets data from an XML service and only does inserts.

```
xml_data := xmltype(GET_XML_F('http://test.example.com/mywebservice');
--GET_XML_F gets the XML text from the site

INSERT INTO TEST_READINGS (TEST, READING_DATE, CREATE_DATE, LOCATION_ID)
SELECT round(avg(readings.reading_val), 2),
  to_date(substr(readings.reading_dt, 1, 10),'YYYY-MM-DD'), SYSDATE,
  p_location_id)
FROM XMLTable(
    XMLNamespaces('http://www.example.com' as "ns1"),
    '/ns1:test1/ns1:series1/ns1:values1/ns1:value'
    PASSING xml_data
    COLUMNS reading_val     VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '.',
            reading_dt      VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '@dateTime') readings
    GROUP BY substr(readings.reading_dt,1,10), p_location_id;
```

I would like to be able to insert or update the data using a merge statement in the event that it needs to be re-run on the same day to find added records.  I'm doing this in other procedures using the code below.

```
MERGE INTO TEST_READINGS USING DUAL
ON (LOCATION_ID = p_location_id AND READING_DATE = p_date)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
        (TEST_reading_id, site_id, test, reading_date, create_date)
        VALUES (TEST_readings_seq.nextval, p_location_id,
                p_value, p_date, SYSDATE)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET TEST = p_value;
```

The fact that I'm pulling it from an XMLTable is throwing me off. Is there way to get the data from the XMLTable while still using the (much cleaner) merge syntax? I would just delete the data beforehand and re-import or use lots of conditional statements, but I would like to avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: Create a view from your select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply put your `SELECT` into `MERGE` statement?

I believe, this should look more less like this:

```
MERGE INTO TEST_READINGS USING (
    SELECT 
        ROUND(AVG(readings.reading_val), 2) AS test
        ,TO_DATE(SUBSTR(readings.reading_dt, 1, 10),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS reading_date
        ,SYSDATE AS create_date
        ,p_location_id AS location_id
    FROM 
        XMLTable(
            XMLNamespaces('http://www.example.com' as "ns1")
            ,'/ns1:test1/ns1:series1/ns1:values1/ns1:value'
            PASSING xml_data
        COLUMNS 
            reading_val     VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '.',
            reading_dt      VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '@dateTime'
        ) readings
    GROUP BY 
    SUBSTR(readings.reading_dt,1,10)
    ,p_location_id
) readings ON (
    LOCATION_ID = readings.location_id
    AND READING_DATE = readings.reading_date
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    ...
;
```

Comment: That worked. This was one of those scenarios where I was literally trying to do it every way except for the obvious one. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean. Sometimes the most obvious solution is the last one to come to mind. :)